# What is causing the empty sequence in my code?

Tags: python, min, valueerror

I'm using a pre-created code called trendy.py: 
https://github.com/dysonance/Trendy

Some part of the code calculates the Max1 and Max2 | Min1 and Min2

For every company i've chosen, i feed the code the last 100 days closing prices.

The code works as expected for some of the companies, but for more than half, it gives me a ValueError.

```
min2 = min(x[(min1 + window):])
```

`ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence`

So to me, it looks like the min1 is the issue. It is unable to be calculated and so is left blank. And then an empty sequence is fed to min2.

**Can someone please have a look and let me know what you think is causing this issue?**

Here is a sample file i've used as input (it gives me the error described).

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xZdSGE05SfyoL9D4akSH0KlV8s2cR1CJLqLlVEzq_4k/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
def gentrends(x, window=1/3.0, charts=True):
    """
    Returns a Pandas dataframe with support and resistance lines.
    :param x: One-dimensional data set
    :param window: How long the trendlines should be. If window < 1, then it
                   will be taken as a percentage of the size of the data
    :param charts: Boolean value saying whether to print chart to screen
    """

    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas_datareader import data, wb

    x = np.array(x)

    if window < 1:
        window = int(window * len(x))

    max1 = np.where(x == max(x))[0][0]  # find the index of the abs max
    min1 = np.where(x == min(x))[0][0]  # find the index of the abs min

    # First the max
    if max1 + window > len(x):
        max2 = max(x[0:(max1 - window)])
    else:
        max2 = max(x[(max1 + window):])

    # Now the min
    if min1 - window < 0:
        min2 = min(x[(min1 + window):])
    else:
        min2 = min(x[0:(min1 - window)])

    # Now find the indices of the secondary extrema
    max2 = np.where(x == max2)[0][0]  # find the index of the 2nd max
    min2 = np.where(x == min2)[0][0]  # find the index of the 2nd min
```

Comment: `min1 + window` is greater than any of the valid indexes of `x`.

Comment: Wouldn't give me an array index out of range? Also, do you know what i can do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this in case someone comes across this issue.

The data that I was feeding was the last 100 days closing prices. However, if you increase the number of data points, then you experience the given error far less.

From Alphavantage API, use "full" rather than "compact" on the daily time series.